# JavaFX how to make a dynamic camera, how to limit the viewport visibility

Tags: java, javafx, game-development

I am learning Java and decided to write a simple game in JavaFX. It generates a maze and you pass it. The size of the maze increases after each passage. And here the problem arises, I set the window to 31 by 31 and when the maze is generated more than the window, part of the maze is naturally lost. So, the question is how you can make a dynamic camera that would follow the character on this:
[image]

The image is visible to the maximum size and everything seems to be in order, but
[image]
shows that the size is larger and part of the maze is no longer visible.

Please tell me the solution to this problem. Just as you can limit the viewport, otherwise the game is still about a maze, but you can see the whole map so that there would be approximately such an effect
[image]

I would be grateful for any help. All files can be seen [here](https://github.com/PaBoS98/MazeGame/tree/master/Maze).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [JavaFX Circular Cutout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093207/javafx-circular-cutout). You simply have to adjust some things to fit your needs (e.g. update the clip as the player moves). Also, if your maze can be bigger than the scene then you'll need to move the maze as the player approaches the edges (or you could keep the player centered and simply move the maze instead of the player).

Comment: Yes, that's about what I want to achieve. scene update, but I can't imagine how to do it yet. But about moving the maze itself, it's a good idea.

Comment: I just looked at your code. I didn't see one `JavaFX` import. If you get an answer, it may not be relevant for your code.